# Trying to auto restart minecraft server every 3 hours

Tags: batch-file, minecraft

I used the code provided in the best answer in this thread: [Need auto-restart script in batch for minecraft server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250361/need-auto-restart-script-in-batch-for-minecraft-server)

However, I'm not sure when the choice function is supposed to run.

Furthermore, I'd rather not have a choice option. I'd like the server just to give a 60 second heads up that it's going to restart and then execute the restart.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the code from the previous answer:

```
@echo off
title minecraft-server-1.8.3
color 0A
prompt [server]:
cls

:start
echo loading server...
java -Xms3G -Xmx3G -jar minecraft_server.1.8.3.jar nogui
cls

:choice
set /P a=do you want to restart[Y/N]?
if /I "%a%" EQU "Y" goto :restart
if /I "%a%" EQU "N" goto :stop
goto :choice


:restart
cls
echo server will restart
TIMEOUT /T 5
cls
goto :start

:stop

cls
echo closing server
TIMEOUT /T 5
exit
```

Comment: The command line `java -Xms3G -Xmx3G -jar minecraft_server.1.8.3.jar nogui` starts `java.exe` to execute Minecraft server and the processing of the batch file by `cmd.exe` is halted until this instance of `java.exe` terminates itself, i.e. execution of Minecraft server is exited for whatever reason. Then the user is prompted with `set /P` (better would be using command `choice`) if Minecraft server should be started again. That is pretty clear.

Comment: If you don't want a choice, replace everything after `cls` after the command line with `java` by `TIMEOUT /T 60` and `goto :start` to have an endless running batch file always waiting 60 seconds after Minecraft server stopped and then starts it again.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow.
As @Mofi mentioned in a comment, you can use TIMEOUT to create wait statement
The script you might want would look something like this:

```
:start
echo loading server...
java -Xms3G -Xmx3G -jar minecraft_server.1.8.3.jar nogui
cls

REM I recommend NOT using TIMEOUT /T for the main wait, this way you can skip it and initiate a restart immediately 

TIMEOUT 10720

REM 3 hours minus 60 seconds to allow for 60 second restart notification

cls
echo server will restart
TIMEOUT /T 60
cls
goto :start
```

(Since you seem to be somewhat new to batch, REM is used to comment out lines)

To answer your question surrounding why the :choice section is a thing:
It is initiated after the :start section, allowing you to either (Y) restart, or (N) stop the server

Comment: Gotcha - and if I wanted the users to be notified, would the 'echo' relay that information in the game. Or would I need to make a line that says

'echo /say server will restart'?

I've learned that /say will relay information in-game.

Comment: `:start
echo loading server...
java -Xms3G -Xmx20G -jar DWAD.jar nogui
cls

TIMEOUT /T 60

cls
echo server will restart in 60 seconds
TIMEOUT /T 30
echo server will restart in 30 seconds
TIMEOUT /T 10
echo server will restart in 10
TIMEOUT/T 1
cls
echo 9
TIMEOUT /T 1
cls
echo 8
TIMEOUT /T 1
cls
echo 7
TIMEOUT /T 1
cls
echo 6
TIMEOUT /T 1
cls
echo 5
TIMEOUT /T 1
cls
echo 4
TIMEOUT /T 1
cls
echo 3
TIMEOUT /T 1
cls
echo 2
TIMEOUT /T 1
cls
echo 1
TIMEOUT /T 1
cls
echo server restarting
cls  
goto :start`

Comment: I ran that test code above but i'm not getting any results, unfortunately!

Comment: Also, apologies - I tried to make it spaced for proper code formatting in my comment but it didn't work :/

Comment: All commands that are mentioned in game will be done through the console (the command prompt window that opens once you start the server .jar) You could do something scuff with focusing that window using a VBscript and autohotkey.

Batch file-->starts/restarts server 
if batch file calls for restart --> start autohotkey script and focus window to console (you could also just use VBscript, but AHK tends to be easier to learn) use AHK to type the command "say 60 seconds until restart"

Comment: Also, can I ask why you're not using spiggot? @JimothyBringus

Comment: I've never heard of spiggot! Can it be used with Forge?

Comment: Also, it's my first time hearing of AHK! I'll check it out.

Comment: Spiggot is a plugin-based launcher, and gives you more flexibility with what you choose to do, I believe it is fully compatible with forge (since it's just a server hosting thing)

Comment: Dang, looks like it's not compatible with forge.

Comment: If I wanted to create a program to do it - what coding language would you recommend? Java?

Comment: If you wanted, you could create a tiny plugin to do it for you (as long as you're running spiggot, it should be easy) so yes, java would be the best. (It could auto-restart the server itself then)